# Error "Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to run this code but I am getting an error saying
**Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call** 
If someone can help me fix this error.

For the full code please visit: https://github.com/aidev1065/WWDC2018_Scholarship_Submission-Accepted/blob/master/README.md

```
        let vc = PageViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: PageViewController does not confirm default initializer like `()` you should customize it in PageViewController (or you can create subclass) `init() { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PageViewController class remove old method init and add new init

`override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: options)
    }`

and your problem will be solved